# How to make a H1-H6 Tags in A new site?

Tags: html

How to create title tags using H1 tags,  I am not familiar with HTML tags

Here is my HTML structure

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Buy RS Gold,Cheap RS Gold- 4RsGold.com
</title>

     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >

<script src="/js/yu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/js/wsj.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/js/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/js/tb.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/js/pagepeel-jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="/css/update.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="/css/pagepeel.packed.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Help!!!

Comment: <h1>Buy RS Gold,Cheap RS Gold- 4RsGold.com </h1>

Comment: I recommend to read a tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Introduction .

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
<h1>Buy RS Gold,Cheap RS Gold- 4RsGold.com</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put content between `<h1>--</h1>` tags like this -

```
<h1>--your content--</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place

```
<h1>,<h2>,<h3>,<h4>,<h5>,<h6>
```

where ever you want that content to appear.

Each open heading tag should be closed using a corresponding close tag i.e

```
</h1>,</h2>,</h3>,</h4>,</h5>,</h6>
```

for 
`<h1>,<h2>,<h3>,<h4>,<h5>,<h6>` respectively

**For your present code,use the below:**

```
<h1>Buy RS Gold,Cheap RS Gold- 4RsGold.com</h1>
```